# When seeding data for devise user model password is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my seeds file I have the following:

```
puts  "Creating Deans User"
user = User.create!(:email => "test@test.com", :password => "test1234", :password_confirmation => "test1234", :name => "Dean Chester", :admin => true)
puts "User created"
```

But when I check this in the console I see the following:

```
[#<User id: 1, email: "test@test.com", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: "2012-08-06 10:02:22", updated_at: "2012-08-06 10:02:22", admin: true, name: "Dean Chester">]
```

And the encrypted password field is blank so what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have:

```
attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password
```

in your model? If so remove it and it will fix your issue.

Comment: Why does `attr_accessor` break things?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing `attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation` in your `User.rb.

Comment: No, I actually fixed it now it was because I had `attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password` in the User model.